# ld: library not found for -lobjc

Tags: ios

I have added FacebookSDK.framework in my project. After that when I am trying to run it on simulator its working fine but while archiving it I am getting the error

```
 ld: library not found for -lobjc
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Not getting any idea how that can be resolved.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode library not found for -lobjc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720595/xcode-library-not-found-for-lobjc)

Answer (score 2):

Without more information, I can only guess that the FacebookSDK.framework suggests that you put `-Objc` into your targets' **Other Linker Flags** in **Build Settings**, and you misspelled it as `-lobjc`.