# xcode library not found for -lobjc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting this error when I am trying to run it on my device, however it working fine when I run it on simulator. Is this a tool chain error or SDK header error? Below is the error message I obtain when compiling.

## Error Message:

```
Ld /Users/KhangYu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobiletimetec-bbuzqjqgmijmomgdmvebkbyasqii/Build/Intermediates/mobiletimetec.build/Debug-iphoneos/mobiletimetec.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mobiletimetec normal armv7
    cd /Users/KhangYu/Desktop/KPTesting/setting
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -L/Users/KhangYu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobiletimetec-bbuzqjqgmijmomgdmvebkbyasqii/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/lib/system -F/Users/KhangYu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobiletimetec-bbuzqjqgmijmomgdmvebkbyasqii/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/KhangYu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobiletimetec-bbuzqjqgmijmomgdmvebkbyasqii/Build/Intermediates/mobiletimetec.build/Debug-iphoneos/mobiletimetec.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mobiletimetec.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AVFoundation -lsqlite3.0 -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/KhangYu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobiletimetec-bbuzqjqgmijmomgdmvebkbyasqii/Build/Intermediates/mobiletimetec.build/Debug-iphoneos/mobiletimetec.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mobiletimetec
```

---

```
ld: library not found for -lobjc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

//-- END --

This is going to be the death of me. Any idea on how to solve it? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

## Solution

Thanks Kevin and Jasper Blues reply and also thanks Reno Jones to edit my post.
After hours of trying to fix this, I renamed the file "libobjc.A.dylib" to "libobjc.dylib"and the error disappear.
P/S: "libobjc.A.dylib" - located in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer‌​/SDKs/*/usr/lib/, thanks again to Kevin.

Comment: It's a missing library, sort of between a toolchain error and sdk headers.

Comment: What sdk are you using? Run `ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/*/usr/lib/libobjc*` and tell us what it shows.

Comment: Your "Solution" completely works for Xcode 6:

I copied `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib` to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib`... 

What I don't understand is... why?

Comment: Based on this other question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595974/ld-library-not-found-for-lobjc -- it's most likely one of the libs that you have loaded that expects that name of the library, e.g., Facebook.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that it works on the Simulator, but not the device because you've specified separate 'OTHER LINKER FLAGS' for both 'Debug' and 'Release' configurations. You'd usually do this if you're linking in a debug framework such as 'Reveal', 'DCIntrospect', etc.

The one for 'Release' looks to be incorrect. It should be '-Objc' and not '-lObjc' - we're telling the compiler that we're using Objective-C itself, and not to load a library called 'Objc'.

**To correct:**

- In Xcode, click on the target for your App.
- Open the 'Build Settings' tab.
- Search for 'Other linker flags' - so you're not overwhelmed by options.
- Correct the 'Release' config. Change '-lObjc' to '-Objc'

[image: flags]

Comment: See solution in question under "Solution"

Comment: The question never becomes second nature, because it's most likely something to do with one of the Libraries that your Binary is linked to. So it's not in Build Settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to rename "libobjc.A.dylib", just re-link it like : ln -s ./libobjc.A.dylib ./libobjc.dylib

Comment: That would work too, but I'm wondering why this is all necessary